# WordPress website pages are redirecting to adult site pages

Tags: wordpress

I have a website built on WordPress platform. Today, when I opened the website and when I clicked anywhere on the website, adult site pages are opening up continuously.

Can anyone please suggest what could be done to resolve the issue?

Comment: Sounds like your site has been hacked. https://www.wordfence.com/learn/has-my-site-been-hacked/

Comment: Can you provide site url so i can check what is caused and how to get rid of it

Comment: http://www.digitalthinkerz.com

Comment: Your site have some inauspicious code. Check index.php and wp-config.php and other files to remove the code

Answer (score 1):

Your site is hacked by someone and some script injected in your WordPress installation or database which causing to load this video your website need to scan your website using plugin like `SECURI` You can get this on [Securi.net](https://sucuri.net/)

**Here are some solutions that you can try(Remember to take a backup before using this)**

- Check and clean all your recently modified files
- Contact your hosting provider if you are not using dedicated server.
- If you have some inactive themes and plugins which you don't need more remove them.Hackers can hide script there. 
  -You can upload new word-press core files which you haven't customised.
- Install fresh copy of themes and plugins if you not customised them.
- Change your secret keys in your wp-config file.
- Check users in your word-press and delete suspected ones.
- Check permission of your installation directory .if not secure them make changes.
- Change you WordPress password

If this all not works to solve problem let me i will look into it.